# FOREACH printing all of its element

Tags: php, arrays, html, codeigniter, object

I just want the table show the category name rather than showing its ID to the user...So I just added $data['category'] object in my Controller

**Controller Code:**

```
$Query="group by product_image order by product_id";  
$data["products"] = $this->insert->Select('product',$Query);            
foreach ($data['products'] as $waste) {             
    $qry = "where id=".$waste->product_category;
    $cat[] = $this->insert->select('category',$qry);
}
$data['category'] = $cat;

//print_r($data["products"]);
$this->load->view('manage/product/list',$data);
```

**View Code:**

```
  if(!empty($products)) { 
                                $l=0;
                                 $base_url=$this->config->item('base_url');
                   $tot = count($products);     

                                foreach($products as $products_info) {

                                $l++; ?>
                        <tr>
                          <td valign="middle"><div class="checkbox check-default">
                             <!-- <input type="checkbox" value="3" id="checkbox2" />
                              <label for="checkbox2"></label> !-->
                            </div></td>
                          <td valign="middle"><?php echo $products_info->product_id;?></td>
                           <td valign="middle"><?php echo $products_info->product_code;?></td>

                          <td valign="middle"><?php echo $products_info->product_name;?>-<?php echo $products_info->prod_weight;?></td>
                            <td valign="middle"><a  target="_new" href="<?php echo  $base_url. "product/".$products_info->product_image;?>"><img src="<?php echo  $base_url. "product/".$products_info->product_image;?>" width="75" height="30" alt="" /></a></td>  
                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $products_info->product_amount; ?></td>

                              <td valign="middle">
                  <?php foreach($category as $cat) { ?>
                    <?php echo $cat[0]->category_title; ?>
                  <?php } ?>
                  </td>

                         <td><?php  if($products_info->status==1) {?>    
                                    <button  Placeid="<?php echo $products_info->id;?>"   action='1' class="btn btn-mini btn-success status-btn">Approved</button>
                                    <?php  } else { ?>
                                    <button Placeid="<?php echo $products_info->id;?>" action='0' class="btn btn-mini btn-danger status-btn">UnApproved</button>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                    </td>
```

The Output image of this Code => [image: Click here]

but I just want to show the correct category to the corresponding row..So please help to get off from this...Waiting for possible solutionzzz

Comment: No need multiple query : simple use INNER JOIN .

Comment: Thank you bro...Its working...

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need `multiple` query `:` simple use `INNER JOIN` .

```
select * from product as p inner join category as c on p.product_category=c.id
```